# Databound Checkbox list with textboxes in a webform

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, webforms

I'm having trouble coming up with a solution for the following problem and i was wondering if someone here would help me out.

I need to pull a list of supplies from a db table and list them along with two textboxes (one for quantity, and another for manufacturer)

so the list would look something like this.

```
checkbox for supply 1 | Quantity | Manufacturer
checkbox for supply 2 | Quantity | Manufacturer
```

..

I also need to store all of the checked items in a db table. 
I'm not sure how i should go about doing this. I've heard some talk about a repeater control being useful but i've not come across any examples that do this type of thing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the ListView for things like this, but Repeater probably woudl work too; simply create the ItemTemplate with these controls.  On a button click, you can loop through the ListView.Items collection, using FindControl to find the checkbox, and if checked, get the textbox values.

It's pretty easy to setup.